# How can I expand the micropost model from Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, methods

I've gone through Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial, and I'd like to expand the micropost model to allow a user to post an item that contains a keyword, price range, and condition field. I've replaced the "content" method in his tutorial with these new methods in the micropost form, micropost model, db migration, factories, and controller. However, when I try to load the form, I get the following error:

```
Showing C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/shared/_micropost_form.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined method `keyword' for #<Micropost:0x54bd7e0>
Extracted source (around line #4):


  <%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :keyword, placeholder: "iPhone 5 16gb" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">


Trace of template inclusion: app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app
```

_micropost.html.erb code:

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: micropost.content %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

microposts_controller.rb code:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end

end
```

factories.rb code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  factory :micropost do
    keyword "iPhone 5"
    price "500"
    condition "used"
    user
  end
end
```

[timestamp]_create_microposts.rb code:

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :microposts do |t|
      t.string :keyword
      t.integer :price
      t.string :condition
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

micropost.rb code:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :keyword, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :price, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :condition, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

_micropost_form.html.erb code:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :keyword, placeholder: "iPhone 5 16gb" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :price, placeholder: "$350-400" %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :condition, placeholder: "Used" %>
  </div>


  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

How can I correctly define these new methods, and make it so that the three attributes are saved in the db under one post every time they're submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

download that, run that application.  open your db... it'll be wherever your app is... then db/development.sqlite3

click on the `browse data` tab.  switch to your microposts.  are your new columns in there?  probably not...

my guess is you just went into your migration files and started tinkering.  no no.

once you run a db:migrate, your database is built.  any changes that you want to make have to be added in the form of a new migration or rollback.

so in your case... you'll probably want to to run `rails g migration add_price_to_microposts`, which will create a new file under db/migrate.

```
class AddPriceToMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :microposts, :keyword, :string
    add_column :microposts, :price, :integer
    add_column :microposts, :condition, :string
  end
end
```

your other option is to rollback.  `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20131130180735`.  this will kill your table... but that's probably ok in your case.  now you can go back into that migration file... make the changes that you want in the form of `t.sting :whatever`, then when you're content, `rake db:migrate` to rebuild the table.

Answer (score 0):

try run migration (if it has not run yet) and restart server

Comment: I did in fact forget to do that, however after doing it I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: Approve that `schema.rb` has table/column microposts/keyword. And I do not see action `new` in controller - in what action do you render the form?

Comment: I think I know what controller action you use `render 'static_pages/home'` - ok. Another way to localize a problem is: load your rails console (if it was loaded exit it and run again). Perform `Micropost.new.keyword` - do you have an error or you get `nil`?

Comment: I get an error saying undefined method 'keyword', even after I fixed the schema.rb

Comment: what do you mean "even after I fixed the schema.rb"? What way did you fix it? It looks like you have problem with migrations: you should have running all migrations and then start server or console! Maybe you created a migration(s), run it and then change it (them) and run `rake db:migrate` again - it is wrong, because modified migration is not applied.